# how can i send message to particular user using socket io in mern app

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, messaging, mern

this is my message schema code i want to send messages to particular user with socket io and im using mern stack for it im new to  socket how can i send message to particular users one to one and how can store it in this schema

```
const MessageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    conversation:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'conversations',
    },

    to:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'user',
    },

    from:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'user',
    },

    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})
```

this is my server code

```
  io.on('connection', (socket) => { /* socket object may be used to send specific messages to the new connected client */
  console.log('connection established',socket.id);
  socket.on('send', (data)=>{
    console.log("username is",data)
  });
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    io.emit('message','user left')
  })
});
```

this is client code my message component.here i have list of users who are currnt users friends how can i send msg to particular user using socket and store messages in message schema

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserService from "../services/userservice";
import {getUsersFriend} from "../services/messageservice";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const SOCKET_IO_URL = "http://localhost:4000/";

export default class Messages extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.socket = io(SOCKET_IO_URL)
        this.state = {
            currentUser: UserService.getCurrentUser(),
            isLoading:false,
            userdetails:[],
            show:false,
            username:'',
            socketConnected:false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchUser()
        this.socket.on('connect',()=> {
            this.setState({ socketConnected : true})
            // console.log("connection")
        })
    }

    async fetchUser(){
        try{
            const {currentUser} = this.state
            console.log(currentUser)
            const data = { userid : currentUser.user._id }
            console.log(data)
            let user = await getUsersFriend(data)
            this.setState({ userdetails: user });
            console.log(user)
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    showMessageSpace(elementusername){
        this.setState({
            show: true,
            username:elementusername
          });
        // console.log(elementusername)
    }

    SendMessage(username){
        if(this.state.socketConnected){
            console.log(username)
            this.socket.emit('send',username);
        }
    }

    render(){
        const { currentUser ,isLoading,userdetails} = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return (<div><p>Loading...</p></div>);
        }

        if(!currentUser){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Redirect  to='/login' />
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Messages</h1>
                <div>
                    <p>Users</p>
                    {' '}
                    <ul className="collection">
                        {userdetails.map((element) => {
                            return(
                                <div key={element._id}>
                                    <li>{element.username}{' '}<input 
                                    type="button" 
                                    id={element._id}
                                    value="Message"
                                    onClick={this.showMessageSpace.bind(this,element.username)} ></input></li>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                        }
                    </ul>
                    {' '}
                </div>
                {' '}
                    <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                {' '}
                <div>
                {
                    this.state.show &&
                    (<div>
                        <h2>Username : {' '}{this.state.username}</h2>
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            Body
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            {' '}
                            <input 
                            type="text"
                            ></input>
                            <button onClick={this.SendMessage.bind(this,this.state.username )}>Send</button>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                    </div>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }
}
```

i added message and username and it is console logging correctly how can i store and fetch those messages in react

Answer (score 0):

In socket.io, there is only a capability to send from client to server or server to client.

So, if you want to send a message from clientA to clientB, then you have to send it via the server.  First, you design a particular socket.io message for this use.  Let's call it `"sendToUser"` where the data is an object:

```
{
   targetUser: "clientB",
   msg: "Hi"
}
```

So, when clientA wants to send to clientB, it does this to send the message and the target user to your server:

```
socket.emit("sendToUser", {targetUser: "clientB", msg: "Hi"}
```

The server then has a listener for the `"sendToUser"` incoming message.  When the server gets that message, it has to have some way to look up the socket.io connection socket object for "clientB".  When it finds that, it does:

```
socketB.emit("sendToUser", {msg: "Hi", from: "clientA"}
```

Then your client, of course, has a listener for `"sendToUser"` and when it receives that, it gets the message and who it is from and can act accordingly for your application.

---

Now, there are a couple things missing here.  First, you have to have some sort of association on your server between sockets and usernames.  Where exactly the user name comes from is application specific, but typically the user would login and after login, your server would know which user was which from their login cookie and/or a session object.  Then, when that same user makes a socket.io connection, you can record which user this is.  When they connection, you may also want to store their connection in some sort of lookup object so you can do an efficient lookup by username.

If, when they connect to your server, you also record their username as a property on the socket object, that will be useful later.

So, once you have this efficient lookup by username, you can just look up the targetUser name and get their socket and then send to them.

And, when you want to know who the "from" username is, you can just read a property on the from user's socket object to get their username.

Comment: could you tell me more aboyr targetuser i didnt get that how should i pass  target users username i have to do it in react code right

Comment: @PratikZinjurde - Well, if one user wants to send a message to some other user, then your app must have some sort of user naming system right that is exposed to users.  You just need to make sure your server keeps track of which username is on which socket.  Then, your client decides who they want to send a message to and sets that as the `targetUser` field in the message they send to the server.  Yes, you have to do that in react code - that's your client.

Comment: SendMessage(username){
        socket.on('connect',data => {
            console.log("connection",data)
            console.log(username)
        })
    }     <input type="text"></input>
                            <button onClick={this.SendMessage.bind(this,this.state.username )}>Send</button>  rhis is console logging anything

Comment: yes i have username unique for evry user and im fetching that correctly like in the post message componenet when i click for particular username its fetching that user

Comment: hello @jfriend00 i have an error while doing one to one messaging should i send you that

Comment: @PratikZinjurde - That sounds like you should write a new question and show your actual code and the error and describe what you want help with.  If this answer provided an answer to your original question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595821/how-can-i-solve-this-i-am-able-to-send-msg-and-receive-but-it-is-not-one-to-one?r=SearchResults    
Here is the code and questionit’s my second handle

Answer (score 0):

You have to have at least 1 server and 1 client to have working example.
In above code i can only see client side code.

So first create server that connect with that socket

Nodejs code is

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', client => {
  client.on('eventName', data => { /* … */ });
  client.on('disconnect', () => { /* … */ });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Then in React code you can

```
socket.emit('eventName',data => {
            console.log("connection",data)
        })
```

And also server can emit on eventName event

---

in your componentDidMount you can set state if socket get connected

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
    // set state here e.x. socketConnected:true

});
```

And in your button click

```
const sendMessage = () => {
        if(this.state.socketConnected){
        socket.emit(`eventName`,{message:"isTHIs"}})
       }
    };
```

define socket as

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';


this.socket = io(APP_SERVER_IP) // in constructor
```

Comment: ok the data should be taken from react like when i click send button right

Comment: the react code i should put it in onclick event for send button right and how can i get the input data i put in input filed

Comment: SendMessage(username){ socket.on('connect',data => { console.log("connection",data) console.log(username) }) }                                                                                        
 <input type="text"></input> <button onClick={this.SendMessage.bind(this,this.state.username )}>Send</button> rhis is console logging anything

Comment: how can i send message info of input to socket.emit