# How can i solve this i am able to send msg and receive but it is not one to one messaging socket io react

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io, message, p2p

I tried reading articles and this is what i get out of it how can i strictly make one to one messaging and how can i make group messaging separately too also when i switch user in private msg i want to get empty showmessagespace but it is showing messages from previous user and when third user sends a msg both users are able to see the msg.

How can i make it one to one msg and change user on clicking particular user message button (message button is working properly it is toggling user). My first aim is for private messaging.

Server code:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

// Assign socket object to every request
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.io = io;
  next();
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
  console.log('connection established',socket.id);
  // io.emit('New Connection')
  socket.on('send', (data)=>{
    console.log("Receive data from single username",data)
    socket.join(`${data.username}`)
    io.emit('send',data)
    socket.to(`${data.username}`).emit(`${data.username}`,data)
  });
  
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    io.emit('message','user left')
  })
});
```

React code :  When i click on message button of other user the msg i send goes to both the previous and to whose message button i clicked and all msg are shared between them

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserService from "../services/userservice";
import {getUsersFriend} from "../services/messageservice";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const SOCKET_IO_URL = "http://localhost:4000/";

export default class Messages extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.socket = io(SOCKET_IO_URL)
        this.state = {
            currentUser: UserService.getCurrentUser(),
            isLoading:false,
            userdetails:[],
            show:false,
            username:'',
            message:'',
            socketConnected:false,
            messages:[]
        };
        this.onTextboxChangeMessage = this.onTextboxChangeMessage.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchUser()
        this.socket.on('connect',()=> {
            this.setState({ socketConnected : true})        })
        this.socket.on('send',(data)=>{
            console.log('component did mount',data)
                this.setState({messages:[...this.state.messages,data]})            
        })
    }

    async fetchUser(){
        try{
            const {currentUser} = this.state
            console.log(currentUser)
            const data = { userid : currentUser.user._id }
            console.log(data)
            let user = await getUsersFriend(data)
            this.setState({ userdetails: user });
            // console.log(user)
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    showMessageSpace(elementusername){  //with this i click on another user and username of that particular user comes
        const {currentUser} =this.state
        this.setState({
            show: true,
            username:elementusername
          });
    }

    onTextboxChangeMessage(e){
        this.setState({ message:e.target.value})
    }

    SendMessage(username,message,senderusername){
        const {messages} =this.state
        if(this.state.socketConnected){            
            console.log('if condition test',username,message,senderusername )
            this.socket.emit('send',{username,message,senderusername});
            console.log('condition username',`${username}`,  )
            this.socket.on(`${username}`, (d)=>{
                    this.setState({messages:[...messages,d]})
               
            })
        }
        this.setState( { message:'' })
    }

    

    render(){
        const { currentUser ,isLoading,userdetails,message,messages} = this.state;
        console.log(messages)
        if (isLoading) {
            return (<div><p>Loading...</p></div>);
        }

        if(!currentUser){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Redirect  to='/login' />
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Messages</h1>
                <div>
                    <p>Users</p>
                    {' '}
                    <ul className="collection">
                        {userdetails.map((element) => {
                            return(
                                <div key={element._id}>
                                    <li><Link to={`/dashboard/profile/:${element._id}`}>{element.username}</Link>{' '}<input 
                                    type="button" 
                                    id={element._id}
                                    value="Message"
                                    onClick={this.showMessageSpace.bind(this,element.username)} ></input></li>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                        }
                    </ul>
                    {' '}
                </div>
                {' '}
                    <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                {' '}
                <div>
                {
                    this.state.show &&
                    (<div>
                        <h2>Username : {' '}{this.state.username}</h2>
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            <h3>Body</h3>
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                {messages.map((msg,key) =>{
                                    return(<li key={key}><span>{msg?.message}</span></li>);
                                })
                                }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            {' '}
                            <input 
                            type="text"
                            name="message"
                            value={message}
                            onChange={this.onTextboxChangeMessage}
                            ></input>
                            <button className='btn btn-info' onClick={this.SendMessage.bind(this,this.state.username,this.state.message,currentUser.user.username )}>Send</button>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                    </div>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have basic knowledge in socketio. I think i managed to send private messages in my test project.

**this example is for private message only**

Here is the solution i followed to send private messages.

in client side when you connect to socketio you need to pass unique user id it maybe firebase client Uid or jwt id like this:

```
    await socketIO.io('http://localhost:3000', {
          query: {
            userId: val,
          }
        });
```

now in backend you need to have an array object with this userId as key and corresponding socketId(You will get socketId when user connects) like this:

```
socket.on("connect", () => {
  // write your logic to add userId and socketId
 //  get socketId by calling socket.id and for passed userId socket.handshake.query.userId
 socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    // remove the user from array object using socketId
  });
});
```

now at this point you have online users (who are connected to socket) with your userId and current socketId emit this user array object

```
 io.emit('users', users);
```

now you can send private message like(**socketid you will get from user array object**) :

```
   io.to(socketid).emit("new_message",{to:to, from: from, msg:msg,date:date}); //for sending private message,
```

I have a semi completed project if you want have a look:
[frontend (Angular)](https://github.com/xXCHINNAXx/chat-app) , [backend(nodejs)](https://github.com/xXCHINNAXx/chat-app-backend)

Comment: can i do it with userid of particular im uing usernamee which is also unique  also when i add this io.to(data.username).emit('sended',data) it is not receiving data from sender

Comment: you can look at server code and client code i thing there is some fundamental mistake which im not able to understand/solve

Comment: io.to() takes socket id not user id check this https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: when i tried this still when i click on new user and send msg both of them are receiving msg

Comment: Hey can I pass senderid  in io.to() while editing msg

Comment: You can only pass socketId in io.to()